# How to test "Payment Gateway" without making real payments?

Tags: testing, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to perform rigrous testing on `Payment Gateway(2checkout)` and `Pay Pal`. For testing, I need to simulate a large number of successful, failed and halted transactions (transaction stopped due to system crash/reboot). But I don't want to make actual payments.

**1. Is there any way I can make a test transaction on payment gateway, using fake card numbers or something else.**

**2. What are the possible advance testing scenarios for Payment Gateway testing?**

For example:

1. Changing the amount, unmask CVV or card from Inspect
   element.
2. List item

Answer (score 2):

There are two options :

1. Using the [PayPal Sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/) (Application Testing), or
2. Using Dependancy Injection (Unit Testing).

Both would work but I would suggest a Dependancy Injection approach. Assuming you have a separate object that only interacts with PayPal and then other objects that do your actual application logic (and error handling, etc) then you can just create a dummy version of the PayPal interaction object (that always returns true, or conditionally returns false, whatever) and then test your various application classes in detail.

Comment: This can be done even when we have integrated the payment gateway with our website??

Comment: which do you mean, the paypal sandbox approach or the dependency injection approach?

Comment: I meant when I click "Submit", I get navigated to "2checkout" to enter my card details etc. After that I get navigated to bank's page and from there back to website on products page.What do you call it dependency injection or sandbox, I dont know any thing about these two.

Comment: I've included a link in my answer to the PayPal sandbox page, did that contain anything of use to you?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you only one solution, look at [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) Git PayPal-Android SDK and go through the README.md file. Last link tells you how to create a sandbox PayPal account to create dummy transactions across your sandboxed account developer account.

If you have doubts, you can refer [Part 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-1/) and [Part 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-2/) of AndroidHive tutorial for this.